# Conditional Terraform Output with heredoc

Tags: terraform, heredoc

Using Terraform `1.1.4`, I'm trying to output the result of a file creation in Terraform and want to use a conditional to skip this output if a variable evaluates as false. This is simple to do in the traditional sense but when using heredoc, I'm finding that there doesn't seem to be a way to make this work but I wondered if it is that I just don't know a way.

Here's an example of the output which works fine without the conditional.

```
output "my_created_file" {
  description = "Output of the newly created file with a KMS arn in it."
  value       = <<EOF
---
creation_rules:
  - kms: ${aws_kms_replica_key.this[0].arn}
EOF
}
```

And here is how I was approaching the conditional:

```
output "my_created_file" {
  description = "Output of the newly created file with a KMS arn in it."
  value       = var.enable_file_creation ? <<EOF
---
creation_rules:
  - kms: ${aws_kms_replica_key.this[0].arn}
EOF : "[INFO] This file was skipped."
}
```

This clearly won't work but I'm not sure how to get around it. Thanks for looking.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this on my own by referring the resource attribute directly and it still results in a similar output.

```
output "my_created_file" {
  description = "Output of the newly created file with a KMS arn in it."
  value       = var.enable_file_creation ? local_file.this[0].content : "[INFO] File Creation Skipped."
```

Which results in an output (if true) of:

```
my_created_file = <<EOT
---
creation_rules:
  - kms: arn:aws:kms:us-east-1:111111111111:key/mrk-a111a111aaaa111111111111aaa1aaaa

EOT
```